# overridePendingTransition not work in adapter(android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want run new Activity in Adapter use animation, but i have some error

```
06-19 09:54:29.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11464): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 09:54:29.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast
 to android.app.Activity 06-19 09:54:29.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):
    at apdapters.NewsAdapter$3.onClick(NewsAdapter.java:134) 06-19
 09:54:29.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):     at
 android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517) 06-19 09:54:29.253:
 E/AndroidRuntime(11464):   at
 android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155) 06-19
 09:54:29.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):     at
 android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 06-19
 09:54:29.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):     at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 06-19
 09:54:29.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):     at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 06-19 09:54:29.253:
 E/AndroidRuntime(11464):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624) 06-19
 09:54:29.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):     at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-19
 09:54:29.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):     at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 06-19 09:54:29.253:
 E/AndroidRuntime(11464):   at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
 06-19 09:54:29.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):   at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576) 06-19
 09:54:29.253: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):     at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Bottom my code, i dont know what its not work

```
holder.newsItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isOnline()) {
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setClass(getContext(), NewsDetali.class);
                    i.putExtra("id", ArrayListNews.get(position).getId());
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(i);

//error this line
                    ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Отсутствует подключение к интернету", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

UPD:

All code

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsObject>{
    ArrayList<NewsObject> ArrayListNews;
    int Resourse;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater vi;

    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    final View imageLayout;
    //final ProgressBar  spinner;

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<NewsObject> objects, ImageLoader imageLoader) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        ArrayListNews = objects;
        Resourse = resource;
        this.context = context;

        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.imageLoader = imageLoader;

        imageLayout = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, null);
        //spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = vi.inflate(Resourse, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/AvenirNext-Regular.ttf");

            holder.imageNews = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageNews);
            holder.nameNews = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameNews);
            holder.dateNews = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateNews);
            holder.newsItem = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.newsItemAdapter);
            holder.loadImg = (PlayGifView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.loading_bg);

            holder.nameNews.setTypeface(face);
            holder.dateNews.setTypeface(face);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        imageLoader.displayImage(ArrayListNews.get(position).getImageLink(), holder.imageNews, null, new ImageLoadingListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View arg1, FailReason arg2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1, Bitmap arg2) {

                int color = Color.parseColor("#4D000000"); //The color u want             
                holder.imageNews.setColorFilter(color);
                holder.nameNews.setText(ArrayListNews.get(position).getName());
                holder.dateNews.setText(ArrayListNews.get(position).getDate());
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0, View arg1) {
                Log.e("Script", "OnLoadeingStarted");
            }
        }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressUpdate(String uri, View view, int current, int total) {
                Log.e("Script", "OnProgressUpdate" + uri + " " + total);
            }
        });




        holder.newsItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), NewsDetali.class);

                    i.putExtra("id", ArrayListNews.get(position).getId());
                    i.putExtra("title", ArrayListNews.get(position).getName());
                    i.putExtra("image", ArrayListNews.get(position).getImageLink());
                    i.putExtra("description", ArrayListNews.get(position).getDescription());
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    context.startActivity(i);


                    //danger line!!! Error this
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageNews;
        public TextView nameNews;
        public TextView dateNews;
        public RelativeLayout newsItem;
        public PlayGifView loadImg;
    }



}
```

Comment: the error message says it all: you are trying to use `context` which is of type `Application` as `Activity`, which it is not.

Comment: @hoijui i try fix this many times, but i dont fix this. Please tell me if you know how to do it

Comment: i find solution..problem is you have  use context  in both place..change like this  Context mycontext; then this.mycontext = context; then use ((Activity) mycontext ).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);...problem solved

Comment: @sasikumar thanks for the answer. If I understand correctly, create another variable type `Context mycontext;` and in constructor `this.mycontext = context;` and then i use like this `((Activity) mycontext ).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);` if i use this i have error `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity` tighter mistake that was before

Comment: A possible cause for this is that you failed to define the application in the manifest. Make sure that your manifest includes something in the lines of:

<application android:name=".MyApp"...
</application>

Comment: @sasikumar class whitch use this adapter add in manifest.

Comment: no need to add adapter in manifest.but  check your  manifest contain <application android:name=".MyApp".>........ </application>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change like this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("key", 1); //Your id
intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
startActivity(intent);
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);
```

then receive like   in newActivity

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
int value = b.getInt("key");
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but i have erro `The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}` in line `getActivity()`

Comment: use fragment? or activity?

Comment: In activity means  remove  getActivity() just call overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);

Comment: i use `ArrayAdapter` its code in adapter. I want when click element in adapter i go new activity and show animation

Comment: overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right); only enough

Comment: when i use only `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right); only enough` i have error  `The method overridePendingTransition(int, int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}`

Comment: ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right); this also error?

Comment: Yes, I have an error that described in the description of the issue

Comment: i find solution..problem is you have use context in both place..change like this Context mycontext; then this.mycontext = context; then use ((Activity) mycontext ).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);...problem solved

Answer (score 23):

This might help

```
Activity activity = (Activity) context;
activity.startActivity(intent);
activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.act_start_in_from_right, R.anim.act_start_out_to_left);
```